# Firebird connection DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, connection, firebird

I use firebird database. and C# connection use Oledb. My service running my localhost but change connection string localhost to Ip adress dont connection an error. Error description is DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21)

Web.Config Code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>

    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="baglantiCumlesi"        
         connectionString="Provider=LCPI.IBProvider.3;Data Source=DEDEDE; Location=E:\Publish\Data\B2C.FDB; Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True ctype=WIN1254; Persist Security Info=True; auto_commit=True; auto_commit_level=4096;dbclient_library=fbclient.dll; dbclient_type=fb2.0; Trusted_Connection=yes; connection reset=false; connection lifetime=0; enlist=true; min pool size=1; max pool size=100; User ID=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey;" 
         providerName="System.Data.OleDb"
    />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

C# Code

```
string baglantiCumlesi = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["baglantiCumlesi"].ConnectionString;

OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection(baglantiCumlesi);
            baglanti.Open();

            string sorgu = "SELECT P.ADISOYADI, UNVANI, T.DAHILI ,'<a href=mailto:'||EMAIL||'>'||EMAIL||'</a>' AS EMAIL"+
                           " FROM PERSONEL P"+
                           " LEFT JOIN TELELINK L ON L.INTERNAL = P.PERSONEL_NO"+
                           " AND L.SINTERNAL = 'PERS' AND L.VARSAYILAN = 'E'"+
                           " LEFT JOIN TELEFONL T ON T.TELEFON_NO = L.TELEFON_NO"+  
                           " WHERE WEB_AKTIF = 'E' AND PERSONEL_NO > 0 AND BLOKE = 'H'"+
                           " ORDER BY PERSONEL_KODU";
```

I use debug error point sorgu.

http://i61.tinypic.com/2lapopv.png

Comment: in the **oledberr.h** I see this text for the error **DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED**: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Comment: thx for comment but running local host I dont understand this error. Change location to localhost running but this state not running

Comment: Why do you use OleDB at all? Why don't you use the Firebird .Net Provider?

Comment: if lots of users will use this program, I have connection error

Comment: which errors? Can you post them?

Comment: Going congestion on service use and can not be accessed

Comment: post the complete error. I have no idea what you mean

Comment: complete error this onyl this http://i61.tinypic.com/2lapopv.png

Comment: i find error provider string  is not true. what can i do?

Comment: We need the exception details (including stacktrace). Consider catching the exception and printing the exception to the console (or to log)

Comment: i try it but i got same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i'm running :) change connection string and running.

```
Provider=LCPI.IBProvider.3; Data Source=DEDEDE;
                Location=DEDEDE:E:\Publish\Data\B2C.FDB;ctype=WIN1254; Persist Security Info=True; 
                    auto_commit=True; auto_commit_level=4096;dbclient_library=fbclient.dll; dbclient_type=fb2.0; Trusted_Connection=yes;
                connection reset=false;connection lifetime=0; enlist=true; min pool size=1; max pool size=100;User ID=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem, your original connection string contains the mistake:
"User Instance=True **>>>;<<<<** ctype=WIN1254"

:)